# XNA texture garbage collection

Tags: xna, c#, .net

I use a

```
 Dictionary<string, Texture2D>
```

for storing textures and every texture in the game is a reference to a texture from this dictionary. However when all references are gone, does the GC dispose of the textures (I don't think so as they are still accessible)?

And if it doesn't, how can I count the references to the textures so I can dispose of them manually?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `ContentManager` is already basically a dictionary of strings to textures (and other resources).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because textures are unmanaged resources, you can not garbage collect them like most objects. Use a ContentManager for this task instead. Once you want to release the textures of a content manager, you should call Unload(); like this:

```
Texture2D apple = Content.Load<Texture2D>("apple"); //Content is the default Content manager
//...
//When you don't need them:
Content.Unload(); //removes every loaded texture which were loaded with this content manager.
```

So you could create multiple ContentManagers, for example one for the main menu, one for the game screen, and load the relevant resources with them.